# how do you stop water flowing from a bubble column in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

so under my pond...i have a two holes...both bubble colums leading to an underground spot...i have a one block doorway to get in and out of said columns...both work perfectly except the water flows out of the doorway...how can i stop this from happening without putting blocks there to stop it.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: Water won't flow into buttons, signs, trapdoors, item frames... you can place any of these instead of a full block. But yes, it's difficult to give you a proper answer without a screenshot of your build.

Comment: @AJPerez  Wouldn't buttons and signs require a block to be placed? And yes, please add a screenshot